# Stuck while trying to simplifying this PDE identity

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

This is related to a fluids HW:
Let $u(x)$ be incompressible vector field on n-D space, $x\in \Omega\subset R^n$ and let $\theta(x)$ be a scalar field s.t. $\int_{\Omega} \theta(x)dx=0$, $\nabla.u=0$

$\Omega$ is boundary-less (say n-Torus). This is crucial since this means there are no boundary terms while doing integration by parts.

Let $\theta=\Delta f$

Prove that:
$\int_{\Omega}(\theta) (u.\nabla f)dx =\int_{\Omega}\nabla f.\nabla u.\nabla f dx$

Comment: I find your notation confusing; by $u . \nabla f$ do you mean the dot product of $u$ and $\nabla f$, i.e. $u \cdot \nabla f$?  If so, how do we interpret the triple product $\nabla f  \cdot \nabla u \cdot \nabla f$?  If not, then what?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis From what I can tell, $u$ is a vector-valued function, so $\nabla u$ is a matrix.

Comment: @nonlinearism:  well, that's helpful.  I guess then that by $\nabla f. \nabla u. \nabla f$ aba then means $\langle \nabla f, \nabla u (\nabla f) \rangle$?  What do you think?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Yup!

Comment: Are you sure this expression should not read $\int_\Omega \theta \boldsymbol{u}\cdot \nabla f \mathrm d x = \color{red} - \int_\Omega \nabla f \cdot \big((\nabla u) (\nabla f)\big) \mathrm d x$ ?